# how to use regex patterns to split the sentence in this pattern

Tags: regex

```
"${agentName} commented on your post of  a ${restaurantName} : ${comment}"
```

How can I extract the word `agentName`,`restaurantName`,`comment` from above sentence using regex pattern?

I am not asking you direct question without any knowledge I have tried i am unable to solve it so I asked in this way By the way I am beginner.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know [what flavor of regex you're using](https://regex101.com/). Are you trying to extract the words inside `${ ... }`? Or is `agentName` a stand-in for a real agent name you're trying to extract?

Answer (score 0):

Just use pattern `\${[^}]+}`

Explanation:

`\${` - match `${` literally

`[^}]+` - negated character class - match everything except `}`, one or more times (due to `+` operator)

`}` - match `}` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5XIomp/1)

Comment: Tq sir its helpful to me

Comment: @AkhilRaghav You should accept the answer then (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is something like:

> Patrick Star commented on your post of a Krusty Krab : I simply love the Krabby Patty! Must try!

and your format is defined as:

> ${agentName} commented on your post of  a ${restaurantName} : ${comment}

Then you can extract `Patrick Star`, `Krusty Krab` and `I simply love the Krabby Patty! Must try!` with the following regex:

```
(.+) commented on your post of a (.+) : (.+)
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GQevgECYTHkLre31)

---

Explanation:

1. `.+` means any character (1 and more)
2. `()` is a capture list containing a regular expression part like `.+`, so based on it's index occurrence:

   - $0 will give you the Agent name
   - $1 will give you the Restaurant name
   - $2 will give you the comment